# Using IN vs ANY in CREATE FUNCTION

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.5

I'm trying to wrap my head around how I can go create a function that will work similar to this but unable to make any headway. What do I need to tweak to make this work appropriately.

```
SELECT * FROM get_all_rows ('{Home,Away}','{LF,RL,CENTER}','2016-06-01 00:00:00','2016-06-30 23:59:59')

-- '2016-06-08 12:24:50','2016-06-09 04:59:45','SW'
-- '2016-06-08 07:12:12','2016-06-09 08:55:25','NW'

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_rows (
    tbl TEXT, 
    disp TEXT[], 
    area TEXT[], 
    current TIMESTAMP,
    future TIMESTAMP
) 
    RETURNS TABLE (
        a TIMESTAMP, 
        b TIMESTAMP, 
        c TEXT
    ) AS
$func$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE
  'SELECT
    door_time,
    guard_time, 
    area
  FROM 
  ' || quote_ident(tbl) || '
  WHERE
    disposition = ANY (disp) 
    and area = ANY (area)
    and door_time IS NOT NULL 
    and guard_time IS NOT NULL 
    and arrival >= arrival_begin
    and arrival <= arrival_end';
END 
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: you may want `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`, instead of a simple `EXECUTE` (which is a noop in your current function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in what you did:

- You didn't supply the first argument `tbl` to your function call.
- You used `current` and `future`as parameters, but in the function body they are called `arrival_begin` and `arrival_end` (at least that's what I assume).
- You didn't add the *values* of `disp`, `area`, `current` and `future` to the query, but the *names* of the variables.

A fixed version of the function definition might look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_rows (
    tbl TEXT,
    disp TEXT,
    area TEXT,
    current TIMESTAMP,
    future TIMESTAMP
    )
    RETURNS TABLE (
        a TIMESTAMP,
        b TIMESTAMP,
        c TEXT) AS
$func$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
  'SELECT
    door_time,
    guard_time,
    area
  FROM
  ' || quote_ident(tbl) || '
  WHERE
    disposition = ANY (' || quote_literal(disp) || ')
    and area = ANY (' || quote_literal(area) || ')
    and door_time IS NOT NULL
    and guard_time IS NOT NULL
    and arrival >= ' || quote_literal(current) || '
    and arrival <= ' || quote_literal(future);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing it up. This worked wonderfully. I had to change out the `EXECUTE` to `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`.